# Device Orientation Destroy Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got my app working for the most part, but I've got buttons and text views with text that change based on some state variables. When I change the device's orientation it destroys and recreates the activity in the new orientation. I've tried adding

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

to the manifest file. I've also tried overriding the onConfigurationChanges method to "do nothing" but the text still reverts to default.

I know I can lock the user in to one orientation, but I would rather have the app usable in either orientation.

Alternatively, is there a way to determine which orientation the user opened the app in and lock them in that orientation until they restart the app?

Edit:

Thank you Kabir,

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

works perfectly

Comment: You should upvote and mark as correct answer of Kabir if solves your problem - to help the community to identify the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For API 12 and below:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

if you are targeting API 13 or above

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually orientation changing works by destroying and recreating an activity. Some views are able to save theirs states, others no. `TextView` doesn't save its state (in this case text) as it tends to show static text. If you want to save `TextView`'s state during the configuration changes, you can do as following:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    /*
    1st argument is key, 2nd is value to save
    */
    outState.putString("savedText", myTextView.getText().toString());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    /*
    The argument is key to get saved string
    */
    myTextView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("savedText"));
}
```

These `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` are `Activiy`'s methods.